# How would I define a set so that its ordered pairs are also part of itself?

Tags: set-theory

I'm looking for an approach and can't quite name it.

I want to define (or proof) that I can have the Cartesian Product $\times$ of a set $C$ with itself ($C \times C$) produce ordered pairs which are also part of $C$.

So that is the goal, that's where I want to get to, but I'm not sure how to approach the way there. As in, which axioms and preliminary steps am I missing?

For the sake of the example,

- let $C = \{A, B\}$, then
- with the cartesian product $C \times C = \{ (a, b) : a \in C, b \in C \}$
- and Kuratowski definition of ordered pairs $(a, b) = \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$,

Armed with the simplification of

- $\{A, A\} = \{A\}$, and conversely
- $\{\{A\}, \{A\}\} = \{\{A\}\}$

I can spell out the product as:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
C ⨯ C &=& \{(A,A), & (A,B), & (B,A), & (B,B)\} \\
      &=& \{\{\{A\}, \{A, A\}\}, & \{\{A\}, \{A, B\}\}, & \{\{B\}, \{B, A\}\}, & \{\{B\}, \{B, B\}\}\} \\
      &=& \{\{\{A\}, \{A\}\},  & \{\{A\}, \{A, B\}\}, & \{\{B\}, \{B, A\}\}, & \{\{B\}, \{B\}\}\} \\
      &=& \{\{\{A\}\}, & \{\{A\}, \{A, B\}\}, & \{\{B\}, \{B, A\}\}, & \{\{B\}\}\}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

There I'm stuck and don't know what to search for, actually.

I do realize that $C$ must be declared differently. If there's only two elements in $C$, namely $\{A,B\}$, then none of the product's elements are part of $C$.

How would I need to define $C$, then, to make it contain some elements, and sets of these elements, and sets of sets of these elements?

What I also realize but can't put to any use are statements about the contents of the Cartesian Product:

- $\{A\} \subset C$
- $\{B\} \subset C$
- $X \times Y \subseteq \mathscr P(\mathscr P(X \cup Y))$

But how can I make $C$ be the power set of itself?

---

My ultimate goal is to have a way to describe a scenario where I have some types (here: $A$ and $B$) from a category ($C$) and also get their tuples/ordered sets to be part of the category $C$, which enables (infinite) nesting like $(A, (B, (A, (A, B)))) \in C$, too. That's an actual programming thing I'm doing that I want to express.

Comment: Take the original set $X_0$. Add pairs to it and get $X_1$. Add all pairs of elements of $X_1$ and att to $X_1$ to get $X_2$. And so on for all natural numbers by induction. Then take the union of all these sets

Comment: Would that be the power set of power sets of power sets of ... of $X$? $X_{i-1} := \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathscr P(X_i)$ maybe?

Comment: Ctietze, what you suggested should work. Another possible example is $V_\alpha$ for a limit ordinal $\alpha$.

Comment: If you just want a set $C$ such that $C\times C\subseteq C$ then $C=\varnothing$ works since $\varnothing\times\varnothing=\varnothing$. If you want less trivial examples, given any set $X_0$ you can follow @CrabMan's suggestion to construct a set $C\supseteq X_0$ such that $C\times C\subseteq C$; recursively define $X_{n+1}=X_n\cup(X_n\times X_n)$ and let $C=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty X_n$.

Comment: "But how can I make $C$ be the powerset of itself". This you cannot do. By the Cantor argument, the powerset of $C$ cannot be put into bijection with $C$. If $C$ were its own powerset, then the identity map on $C$ would be such a bijection. Another thing you have to be careful about with constructions such as those attempted here is that any set has to satisfy the axiom of foundation: Any downward sequence $.... A_4 \in A_3 \in A_2 \in A_1$ of sets being elements of their predecessors has to be finite. This axiom is critical in avoiding logical contradictions.